# Android Studio does not open. Just stopped loading on 60% to 70%

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to open my Android Studio 1.2 in Windows 8.1 64bit system. But it's not opening. It was working fine befor two days ago but now I am facing this issue.

- many times I reinstalled it
- change JDK path
- enabled VT-X from BIOS

[image: Please see image]

As you can see on above image that it is stopping here everytime.

After 2 hrs of loading it's giving me below error log.

```
`Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryState'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryState'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:359)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:504)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:486)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem.getInstance(LocalFileSystem.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl$1.beforeFileBasedStorageCreate(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.createFileStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.createStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:185)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.getStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initPersistentComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.initializeComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:566)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ManagingFS'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:268)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:127)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:116)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ApplicationImpl.java:538)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:199)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFileManager.getInstance(VirtualFileManager.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem$LocalFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(LocalFileSystem.java:40)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:116)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:100)
    at org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer.render(DefaultThrowableRenderer.java:58)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:683)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaLogger.info(IdeaLogger.java:185)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.info(Logger.java:97)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:82)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:38)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:53)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:46)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:32)
   `
```

Please give me suggestion how can i solve this issue.

Comment: Can you get some log file? I'm not familiar with Android Studio but it's the only way you can get some help.

Comment: i did not get it ever after this issue

Comment: @noinstance i got this error log after 2 hr. can you please suggest me now how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the firewall and try again.

Check Java is installed properly and set the java home properly.